# How to pass value between two scenarios in gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have two scenarios in my script. I want to pass value of "CreateId" to 2nd scenario. I have saved "CreateId" in 1st scenario.

Error says:

> No attribute named 'CreateId' is defined
>
> jsonPath($.id).find(0).exists, found nothing

**Scenario - 1**

```
val create = scenario("Create")
        .exec(http("post_request_create")
        .post("/api/asdf")
        .headers(headers_10)
        .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{"name": "${randomName()}"}""")).asJSON
        .check(jsonPath("$.id")
        .saveAs("CreateId"))
        )
```

**Scenario - 2**

```
val addTerm = scenario("Add Term")
        .repeat (repeatCount){
        exec(http("Add")

        // NOT WORKING
            //.post("""/api/asdfg/${CreateId}/terms""")

        // NOT WORKING
            .post(session => "/api/asdfg/" + session.get("CreateId").asOption[String] + "/terms")

            .headers(headers_10)
            .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{...somedata...}"""))
            )
        }
val scn = List(create.inject(atOnceUsers(1)),addTerm.inject(nothingFor(10 seconds), atOnceUsers(userCount)))
setUp(scn).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Tried with below code and it worked. Hope it helps others.**

```
var CreateId = ""

Scenario - 1

val create = scenario("Create")
        .exec(http("post_request_create")
        .post("/api/asdf")
        .headers(headers_10)
        .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{"name": "${randomName()}"}""")).asJSON
        .check(jsonPath("$.id")
        .saveAs("CreateId"))
        )

        .exec(session => {
            CreateId = session("CreateId").as[String].trim
            println("%%%%%%%%%%% ID =====>>>>>>>>>> " + CreateId)     
            session}       
        )


Scenario - 2

val addTerm = scenario("Add Term")
    .exec(_.set("CreateId", CreateId)) // Set it here
       .repeat (repeatCount){
        exec(http("Add")
       .post("""/api/asdfg/${CreateId}/terms""")
       .headers(headers_10)
       .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{...somedata...}"""))
            )
        }
val scn = List(create.inject(atOnceUsers(1)),addTerm.inject(nothingFor(10 seconds), atOnceUsers(userCount)))
setUp(scn).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Comment: Hello @Peter, How does this approach work when you run many users concurrent and if the create takes more than 10 seconds ? I have a similar situation, but since the first scenario can take a long time for me, the variable sometimes is not set by the time the second scenario starts.

Comment: Hi Gery, For me In above code 2nd scenario is important, I have to check response of 2nd call so I hold that scenario until I get response from 1st scenario. You can increase the time limit i.e (nothingFor(300 seconds)) based on your calculations of response time.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. My requirement of two scenarios isn't the same but I wanted to set a value and use it over several requests for the same user in a scenario.  But since sessions are immutable my value was gone after the next request was made - because a new session was written based on that latest request/response. Need to store the value outside the session in a variable in order to use it throughout the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue for token where I need to generate the one token from auth services and need to pass to other API. I followed below steps. Hope this will resolve your problem.

```
val create = scenario("Create")
        .exec(http("post_request_create")
        .post("/api/asdf")
        .headers(headers_10)
        .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{"name": "${randomName()}"}""")).asJSON
        .check(jsonPath("$.id")
        .saveAs("CreateId"))
        )
```

then I created

```
val createId = exec(session => session.set("createdId", createdId));
```

Let's say `create` is in different Test object. so created object in calling class.

```
val test = new Test()

val addTerm = test.createId
    .exec(_.set("CreateId", CreateId)) // Set it here
       .repeat (repeatCount){
        exec(http("Add")
       .post("""/api/asdfg/${CreateId}/terms""")
       .headers(headers_10)
       .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{...somedata...}"""))
            )
        }

val addTermScn = scenario("Add Term ").exec(addTerm)
val testScn = scenario("create").excec(test.create)

setUp(

    testScn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)),
    addTermScn.inject(nothingFor(5),rampUsers(vUsers) during (rampUp seconds)),
    //orderLookup.inject(nothingFor(5),rampUsers(vUsers) during (rampUp seconds))
  ).throttle(
    reachRps(tps) in (rampUp second),
    holdFor(duration minutes)
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have general solution which can easy to use. There is several steps how to do it.

Create methods which **get** all session variable from one scenario and another method which **set** this variables:

```
import scala.collection.concurrent.{Map => ConcurrentMap}

def passAnotherSession(implicit transferVariable: ConcurrentMap[String, Any]): Expression[Session] =
    (currentSession: Session) => {
      currentSession.setAll(transferVariable)
    }

def saveSessionToVariable(implicit transferVariable: ConcurrentMap[String, Any]): Expression[Session] =
    (currentSession: Session) => {
      val systemKeys = List("gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts", "gatling.http.cache.contentCache", "gatling.http.cache.dns")
      transferVariable ++= currentSession.removeAll(systemKeys: _*).attributes
      currentSession
    }
```

I defined methods above in my abstract base class which is inherited in all simulations/scenario classes.

---

Then in my simulations/scenario class I defined mutable map (via implicit) for store session variable:

```
import scala.collection.concurrent.{Map => ConcurrentMap}

implicit val setUpSession: ConcurrentMap[String, Any] = new TrieMap()
```

---

Now let's start using the methods.
Below is an example of a scenario that gets the desired variable:

```
val setUpScenario = scenario(...)
.exec(...) // some action with save desired variable 
.exec(saveSessionToVariable) // this save all session variables to above defined implicit map
```

And this is already a scenario that needs a variable:

```
val mainScenario = scenario(...)
.exec(passAnotherSession)    // get variable from setUpScenario
.exec(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification of @Peter's answer in Java.
For some reason the direct modification of the session doesn't work in Java:

```
.exec(_.set("CreateId", CreateId)) // Set it here
```

The value set in the session is discarded after leaving the lambda function.
I solved this by wrapping the value with a feeder:

```
    Iterator<Map<String, Object>> createIdFeeder =
    Stream.generate((Supplier<Map<String, Object>>) () -> 
        Collections.singletonMap("CreateId”, CreateId)
    ).iterator();
```

and adding it to the "Add Term" scenario:

```
ScenarioBuilder addTerm = scenario("Add Term”)
    .feed(createIdFeeder) // Set it here
    .repeat (repeatCount){
```

Comment: "For some reason the direct modification of the session doesn't work in Java" As documented, Session is immutable: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/#setting-attributes